# Pyaudio Recording audio from streaming Python

Tags: python, sockets, streaming, registration, pyaudio

I would like to record using pyaudio in python, the audio streamed through a socket and save it in a *.wav file. 
I want to save everything in wave after so I can process it as I want. For now I have tried to write this code, but it always fails after a while that I compile.

The error is

```
wf.writeframes(b''.join(data1))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected bytes, int found
```

my code for client.py is:

```
import pyaudio, sys, socket, wave
port = 5000
ip = "192.168.1.110"
chunk = 512
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 49000
WAVE_OUTPUT="output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format = FORMAT, channels = CHANNELS, rate = RATE, input =True,output = True, frames_per_buffer = chunk)

#Create a socket connection for connecting to the server:
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((ip, port))
print ("***Registrazione in corso***")
frames=[]
for i in range (0,int(RATE/chunk*20)):
data1=client_socket.recv(chunk)
frames.append(data1)
while True:
#Recieve data from the server:
#data = client_socket.recv(1024)
stream.write(data1,chunk)
wf=wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT,"wb")
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(data1))
#print data
wf.close()   
socket.close()
```

Comment: You are getting a `TypeError` because the open `wav` file want a stream of bytes and you are passing a single `int` value. I think you want to write the entire frame to the file and not just the chunk in `data1`. Try `wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))`. You also need to check/fix the indentation of the code sample above.

Comment: Fanastic! Now I registering all wav audio :D another request...before I could even hear the sound coming out of the speakers , the speakers are now mute but records the wave files ... what has changed ?

Comment: Awesome! Now, I'm not sure about the speakers, but I would start by checking if you really need `stream.write(data1,chunk)`, aren't you reading from the stream and writing to a file? At the end, don't forget to close the stream. `stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `TypeError` because the open `wav` file want a stream of bytes and you are passing a single `int` value. I think you want to write the entire frame to the file and not just the chunk in data1. Try `wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))`. Also don't forget to close the stream at the end.

`stream.stop_stream()
 stream.close()`